# Embed in cogs (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I tried to implement embed message on my cogs file. When I try to use the command, this error pop out on my console.

```
An exception has occurred while executing command `cal`:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord_slash/client.py", line 1352, in invoke_command
    await func.invoke(ctx, **args)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord_slash/model.py", line 209, in invoke
    return await self.func(self.cog, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/calculator/cogs/update.py", line 16, in cal
    self.username = ctx.message.author.display_name
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'author'
```

The error points out that author returns none (from my understanding). Here is my code snippet :

```
@ cog_ext.cog_slash(description = "Calculate your math's query.")
  async def cal(self,ctx,query : str) :
    self.operation = ("").join(query)
    self.evaluate = eval(self.operation)
    self.username = ctx.message.author.display_name
    self.embed = discord.Embed(title = "/Cal", description = "Calculate your math queries.", colour = discord.Color.blurple())
    self.embed.set_footer(text = f"{self.username}'s query evaluated.")
    self.embed.set_author(name = f"{self.username}'s' query.", icon_url = ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
    self.embed.add_field(value = f"{self.operation}", inline = False)
    self.embed.add_field(value = "After evaluated, the result is :", inline = True)
    self.embed.add_field(value = f"{self.evaluate}", inline = True)
    await ctx.send(embed = self.embed)
```

From my instinct, I think in cogs file, author is represented using different keywords. Maybe there's something wrong with my code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What library are you using for the slash commands?

Comment: discord_slash or discord-py-slash-command

Comment: Well the error says that `message` is `None`, not `.author`, so your instinct is wrong there. I don't know anything about this lib so I can't point out where the actual issue comes from though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem here is, that discord-py-slash-commands (or discord-interactions as it was renamed to) returns a `SlashContext` object instead of the regular context object which was used by discord.py. And, since a slash command isn't invoked with a message, the message object is `None`, which is confirmed by the error.

To solve this issue, you should be able to replace `ctx.message.author` to `ctx.author`, which should work, [as stated in their documentation](https://discord-interactions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discord_slash.context.html#discord_slash.context.InteractionContext).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what library you are using or how it works since that does not look like just `discord.py`, but have you tried doing `ctx.author.display_name` instead of `ctx.message.author.display_name`.

Comment: Yup, I have tried but it still didn't work. But thanks for your help.